# Installed application does not create entry in startmenu

Tags: windows-7

For the past months no entries are created in startmenu when I install an application. This is truly annoying. Windows is not my main OS so I am kind of at a loss.

The only clue I could find is this:

> THE SOLUTION IS HERE!What solved the issue was to add Authenticated Users back to the profiles of all files on the system. This may not be the way thing originally were setup but when I copied an outlook folder from Vista OS to my Win 7 OS (both are on my PC) is when the Authenticated Users rights went away. In addition I had to go back into start menu properties and select custom and re-enable Administrative Tool which also went away at some point. Everything is back to normal now.

But I don't really know what this guy is saying.

Anyone with a clue stick, please smack me hard with it.

**[UPDATED]**

Here are screencaps of permissions for start menu folder. All permissions out of view are disabled. It seems adding write permissions may be the way to go, but I am not really sure ...

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Just who is "this guy" anyway, and where did he post this? Perhaps your user profile is corrupt. Are you using an admin account? Do you have other user accounts on the PC? If not, try creating one and see if the same behaviour can be replicated when you log into it and install a new as-yet not installed program.

Comment: @Karan - http://www.tomshardware.com/forum/14358-63-some-start-menu-programs-missing , last comment in thread.

Comment: that is some pretty bad advice. the authenticated users group is very broad, and doing so would significantly reduce system security. for your problem, are you installing the applications for all uses or just for your user?

Comment: @FrankThomas - I tried installing for all users and even as adminstrator, to no avail.

Comment: do you have a folder at C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu and what are its permissions?

Comment: @Frank Thomas - I think you are on to something. Updated question with screenshots of permission / security settings.

Comment: try granting your user Modify control of that folder and see what happens